# Covert Excel to TEXT in VB

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub TextFile_Example7()
Dim sPath As String
Dim FileNumber As Integer
Dim aData As Variant
Dim i As Long, k As Long
    aData = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Value
    sPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\textfiles\"
    On Error Resume Next
    MkDir sPath
    On Error GoTo 0
    sPath = sPath & "Hello_" & Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD_HHmmSS") & ".txt"
    FileNumber = FreeFile
    Open sPath For Output As FileNumber
    For i = LBound(aData) + 1 To UBound(aData)
       For k = LBound(aData, 2) To UBound(aData, 2)
            Select Case LCase(aData(1, k))
                Case "first_name"
                    Print #FileNumber, "First Name=" & aData(i, k)
                Case "last_name"
                    Print #FileNumber, "Last Name=" & aData(i, k)
                Case "email_address"
                    Print #FileNumber, "E_mail Address=" & aData(i, k)
                Case "password"
Rem Skip column, nothing to output
                Case Else
                    Print #FileNumber, aData(1, k) & "=" & aData(i, k)
            End Select
        Next k
    Next i
   Close FileNumber
   Shell "notepad.exe " & sPath, vbNormalFocus
End Sub`
```

In the above code
Problem Statement

I am using this code to convert the excel sheet data into text file but i am having the data in excel sheet upto column 'J' so it only read and write the data upto column 'J'

Solution wanted:- I have data in 'Z' column it is not reading and writing the data into text file

Comment: `Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Value` will store value till next empty row and column. So, do you have any empty column after `Column J`?

Comment: @Harun24HR  Yes I do have empty columns after column J and have one column Z fillled with data. So,  want to read Z column also is it possible ??

Comment: Like colums A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J  have gap and column z

Comment: Yes possible. Then need to change coding for that line.

Comment: How to achieve this ??  @Harun24HR

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the **UsedRange** property of **Worksheet**. It gives you a continuous area which encompasses all the cells that have data. Empty cells will return "" and so check this in your Select statement and skip that column.

NB. This will run on all non-empty cells, so if you have anything beneath your table, the code will try and process that too. You can put in extra checks if that is the case.

```
aData = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
 ...
For i = LBound(aData) + 1 To UBound(aData)
     For k = LBound(aData, 2) To UBound(aData, 2)
        Select Case LCase(aData(1, k))
            Case "first_name"
                Print #FileNumber, "First Name=" & aData(i, k)
            Case "last_name"
                Print #FileNumber, "Last Name=" & aData(i, k)
            Case "email_address"
                Print #FileNumber, "E_mail Address=" & aData(i, k)
            Case "password"
                #Skip column, nothing to output
            Case ""
                #Skip column
            Case Else
                    Print #FileNumber, aData(1, k) & "=" & aData(i, k)
        End Select
    Next k
Next i
```

Comment: "NB. This will run on all non-empty cells, so if you have anything beneath your table, the code will try and process that too. You can put in extra checks if that is the case."